# Did i automate sharepoint quick link webpart using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

getting value from the list and automatical creating a quick link in SharePoint using power automate is this possible

Hii
I'm new to SharePoint, I'm trying to create a dynamic page which means getting value from the list and automatical creating a quick link in SharePoint UI  using power automate is thispossibleb ?
possiblel means  how can I make that I'mm i just stuck the with past week need help.. any buddy can guide me to get this?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create these kind of links with Send an HTTP request actions. You could for example use the SavePage method to set the values of Quick Links web part.

Have a look at this Power Automate thread:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Changing-SharePoint-Quick-links-via-Power-Automate-HTTP/m-p/1671247

Try that approach and if you have any specific questions let us know.